# Push vs poll for subscribe/publish server

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to get clear answer which one is better? poll or push?

In my case there are clients that subscribed on data source. Data source is series of events with specific event id. Every user subscribed on specified events. When new event is published  every subscribed user should get this update. There are other client/server interactions, but i worring mostly about this part.

Currently there are some requirements

1. Totally there would be 10-25 event ids.
2. Every user should get an update after 2-4 seconds
3. Updates are extreamly rare around 1-4 a day or maybe none.
4. We should maximaze max user connected to server. Considered number around 5000 users.
5. User can subscribe only on those events, which he is authorized on.

I'm thinking to use WCF (http or nettcp bindings).

I never developed client/server communication by my own - so any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described seems like you should use **Push**.

It doesn't make sense to poll every few seconds for 1-4 events a day.

An easy setup could be a duplex service using nttcp binding using